# JTable & JTextField used for input. JTable is updateable. DocumentListener used for JTextField. Event doesn't fire. How to get event?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test1 extends JApplet
{

  Object dummya [][] = new Object [9][9];           // Setup 2-Dimensional Arrays

  int inputa [][] = new int [9][9];
  int possiblea [][] = new int [81][9];
  int solveda [][] = new int [9][9];

  String ic = "B";
  String nl = "\n";
  String col_h [] = {"G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", "G8", "G9"};

  Font f = new Font ("Courier", Font.BOLD, 10);
  Font h = new Font ("Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);

  JTextField uc = new JTextField (1);
  JTextField st = new JTextField (75);

  int gs = 55;
  int wl = 1;
  int ts = col_h.length;

  DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel(dummya, col_h) { // Setup the Table Model
    public String getColumnName (int col) {return col_h[col];}
    public int getColumnCount() {return 9;}         // Setup a 9x9 Table with headers
    public int getRowCount() {return 9;}
    public void setValueAt (Object foundValue, int row, int col) {
//      st.setText ("At setValueAt.");
//      inputa[row][col] = (Integer) foundValue;
      fireTableCellUpdated (row, col);
    }
  };

  JTable table = new JTable (dm);               // Create the Table

  public void init () {
    Container c = getContentPane ();                // Get a Container for User View
    Color lc = new Color (240, 128, 128);           // Set Light Coral Color
    c.setBackground (lc);
    c.setFont (f);

    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed (false);      // Setup all the Table rules
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed (false);
    table.setSelectionMode (javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    for (int i = 0; i < ts; i++) {              // Resize Columns & Rows to 40 pixels
      TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
      column.setMinWidth (40);
      column.setMaxWidth (40);
      column.setPreferredWidth (40);
      table.setRowHeight (i, 40);
    }
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener (
      new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
          tableDataChanged (e);
        }
    });

    c.setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER, 340, 0));   // Setup a Layout & add Components
    c.add (new JLabel ("                                                     "));
    c.add (new JLabel ("Challenge", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    c.add (new JLabel ("                                                     "));
    c.add (new JLabel ("By  Author X", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    c.add (new JLabel ("                                                     "));   // Add a pad line
    c.setFont (h);
    table.setGridColor (Color.red);             // Setup Table View
    c.add (table.getTableHeader());             // Add Column Headers
    c.add (table);                      // Show the Table
    c.add (new JLabel ("                                                     "));
    uc.setBackground (lc);
    c.add (new JLabel ("  Enter Command (C,F,H,L,I,P,S): ", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    c.add (uc);                         // Add a User Command Field
    uc.setEditable (true);                  // Allow Input in Command Field
    uc.requestFocusInWindow();
    c.add (new JLabel ("                                                     "));
    st.setBackground (lc);
    c.add (st);                         // Add a Status area
    st.setEditable (false);

    uc.getDocument().addDocumentListener (new DocumentListener() {  // Listen for JTextField command
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        editInput();
      }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        editInput();
      }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
    });
  }

    // The following section is driven by a user command.
  public void run () {                      // To keep the Applet running, just loop

    int loopcnt = 0;
    while (wl != -1) {
      loopcnt++;
      if (loopcnt == 100) {
        try { Thread.sleep (10000); }               // Sleep for 10 seconds to allow solve
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}           // thread to run.
        loopcnt = 0;
      }
    }
  }


  private void editInput () {                   // Scan user command

    try { ic = uc.getText (0, 1); }             // Pick up user command
    catch (BadLocationException be) { return; }
    st.setText ("  User Input is: " + ic);

    if (ic == "C" || ic == "c") clearComponents ();
      else if (ic == "E" || ic == "e") {
      st.setText ("  User Exit.");
      wl = -1;
    }
    else if (ic == "H" || ic == "h") newFrame();
//    else if (ic == "F" || ic == "f") getHintAtFirst();    // Get a hint where only 2 values possible
//    else if (ic == "L" || ic == "l ") getHintAtLast();
//    else if (ic == "I" || ic == "i") StartThread();       // Look into wait and Notify
//    else if (ic == "P" || ic == "p") printGrid();
//    else if (ic == "S" || ic == "s") solveAndShow();
//      else st.setText ("  Invalid Command, try again.");
  }


  public void clearComponents () {              // Clear Arrarys and Table View

    for (int i = 0; i < ts; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < ts; j++) {
        dummya[i][j] = null;
        inputa[i][j] = 0;
        possiblea[i][j] = 0;
        solveda[i][j] = 0;
        table.setValueAt (null, i, j);
      }
    }
    st.setText ("  Table Cleared.");
  }

  private void newFrame () {                    // Setup the Possibles frame
    JFrame possibles = new JFrame ("Grid Possibilities");
    possibles.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    possibles.setBounds (550, 0, 440, 580);
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea ();
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane ();
    possibles.add (ta);
    possibles.add (sp);
    possibles.pack ();
    possibles.validate ();
    possibles.setVisible (true);
  }

  public void tableDataChanged (TableModelEvent e) {        // Process & Edit user input
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int col = e.getColumn();
//    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
//    String cn = model.getColumnName (col);

    for (int i = row; i < ts; i++) {                // Scan the input for values
      for (int j = col; i < ts; j++) {
        dummya [row][col] = table.getValueAt (i, j);
        int newValue = (Integer) dummya [row][col];
        int rc = integerEditor (1, 9, newValue);        // Go check the user input
        if (rc == 0) {
          st.setText ("Input Value is " + newValue);
          inputa [row][col] = (Integer) dummya [row][col];  // Store the grid value
        }

        else st.setText ("Input Value is invalid at " + row+1 + "," + col+1 + ".");
      }
    }
  }

  private int integerEditor (int va, int vb, int value) {   // Edit user input
    if (value < va || value > vb) return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: When posting code don't forget to select the code and then click on the "Code Sample" button so that the code will become properly formatted.

Comment: Don't use "==" to compare Strings. Use the equals(...) method.

Answer (score 3):

```
DefaultCellEditor dce = (DefaultCellEditor)table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
JTextField editor = (JTextField)dce.getComponent();
editor.addDocumentListener(...);
```

Comment: Camickr, I have a JTextField in my snippet called "UC",  I would like to listen for input on this field; so, I setup a listener for it.  What will this code that you gave me above do for me? (I'm trying to see if this will fit my needs).

Comment: Your question mentions a JTable that is editable with a JTextField. I assumed your where talking about the table editor. If that is not the case then why did you mention the JTable in your question? Only post the releavant inforamtion when you ask a question. I would start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on "How to Wrie a Document Listener": http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html. If you need more help the post a proper SSCCE (sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi Camickr, may I add one question to your answer? Using your code I'm able to listen to the editing event of a table editor, but how could I know which cell is being edited inside the code of DocumentListener? I need to write changes to an extern file as soon as the table is edited.

Comment: @boreas, When you create the DocumentListener you would need to pass in the table that you are monitoring as a parameter to the custom DocumentListener. Then in your code you can reference JTable methods like getEditingRow() and getEditingColumn();

Comment: @boreas, I was just thinking that when you use a DocumentListener you get notified every time a character is changed. Instead you may want to get notified only when the user saves the changes. In this case you might find the [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) easier to use.